# error while downloading the file fron the cluster

Tags: cluster

protocol error: unexpected

my ~/.bashrc code is as:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
source /home/marek.szczepanczyk/git/library_2g/conda_watenv.sh
        #source /home/bhawana.sedhai/library/cit_watenv_cmake.sh
        #source /home/bhawana.sedhai/library/cit_watenv_cmake.sh
        #source /home/francesco.salemi/git/cWB/library/cWB-6.4.2.99.test_conda_watenv.sh
        #source /home/waveburst/SOFT/cWB/tags/library/ML_all-sky_O3_patched/O3b_watenv.sh
#source /home/marek.szczepanczyk/git/library_2g/conda_watenv.sh
#source /home/waveburst/SOFT/cWB/tags/library/cWB-OfflineO3-v13/cit_watenv-config-cWB-OfflineO3-v8-O3b-lalsuite-v6.79.sh
#source /home/waveburst/SOFT/cWB/tags/library/cWB-OfflineO3-v14/cit_watenv-config-cWB-OfflineO3-v8-O3b.sh
#source  /home/shubhanshu.tiwari/SHUBH/o3_cwb_o3b/library/library/cit_watenv_shubh.sh

#source /home/marek.szczepanczyk/SOFT/wat-6.2.6-cit/marek_cit_watenv.sh
#source /home/marek.szczepanczyk/git/library_ms/cit_watenv.sh
#source /home/gaukhar.nurbek/cit_watenv-config-cWB-OfflineO3_v12-O3b_config.sh
#export CWB_CONFIG="/home/gaukhar.nurbek/git/config_o3"
#source /home/marco.drago/cit_watenv-config-cWB-OfflineO3_v12-O3b_config.sh
#export CWB_CONFIG="/home/marco.drago/git/cWB/config_o3"
# /home/marek.szczepanczyk/SOFT/wat-6.2.6-cit/marek_cit_watenv.sh
#source /home/gaukhar.nurbek/library/cit_watenv.sh
#source /home/oscar.valdez/SOFT/trunk/oscar.valdez_watenv.sh
#source /home/gaukhar.nurbek/CWB/cit_watenv.sh
#source /home/marek.szczepanczyk/git/library_ms/cit_watenv.sh
```